# How to get 2 request work at same time Async Task?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have 2 class of `AsyncTask` for handling request one for sync and other class for handling other request but when I send sync request and move to other page and request response for second request will get after sync request responds. How I solution this?

Hope any one help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I suggest you take a minute to reformat your question from one massive sentence without any interpunction to something a little more understandable. I'm assuming you'd like a quality answer that helps you solve the problem at hand (although I have no idea what that currently is). Starting with a quality question gets you at least halfway there. As a 2-year member, you should know [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question by now.

Comment: you have any ans ??my friend ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make asyntask run parallel execution by replacing `execute()` with `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)`.

Comment: what is different between both of this??fahim

Comment: @neel If your android:targetSdkVersion is 13 or higher, and you are running on an Android 3.2 or higher device, they will be executed serially.

If you are running on Android 1.5, they will be executed serially.

Otherwise, they will be executed in parallel.

Comment: @neel this vl fix ur problem, if it works then accept the answer for others to refer

Comment: i think this will work when request from same activty when request for sync and move to other activity and send request it will not give respons after sync respons i get after i will get secand request respons @fahim

Comment: this will work irrespective of ur anynstask start from

Comment: i used static object of httpclient i think thats why it throw signalclientconmanger already allocated and socket is close exception so for all request it will used signal object now you have any solution bro exception is 06-24 11:44:11.412: W/SingleClientConnManager(422): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
06-24 11:44:11.412: W/SingleClientConnManager(422): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
06-24 11:44:11.531: E/log_tag(422): Error in http connection java.net.SocketException: Socket closed

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can use `Volley`

Volley offers the following benefits:

1. Automatic scheduling of network requests.
2. Multiple concurrent network connections.
3. Transparent disk and memory response caching with standard HTTP
   cache coherence.
4. Support for request prioritization.
5. Cancellation request API. You can cancel a single request, or you
   can set blocks or scopes of requests to cancel.
6. Ease of customization, for example, for retry and backoff.
7. Strong ordering that makes it easy to correctly populate your UI
   with data fetched ***asynchronously*** from the network.
8. Debugging and tracing tools.

You can easily find a tutorial for it and
It much faster then `AsyncTask` .

For reference check [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)